# How to convince my teammates that spawning numerous threads is a bad design?

Tags: design, .net, teamwork, multithreading

I've stumbled upon this problem when tried to run our application in bad network conditions; it spawns hundreds of threads (which exist long time before termination), and with time the application crashes. However, other developers answered this is "not a bug" and "as designed".
I have a strong gut feeling that spawning so much threads instead of using async calls is defective design, in the first place. However, my teammates disagree.
Any ideas how I can convince them?

UPD can I say that spawning threads for short running tasks is a bad design? What arguments I can use to support this statement?

Comment: The question is, is the application supposed to be able to work in the conditions where you experienced the crash? If it is, you found a bug an need to convince the others of *that*. If it isn't, then your test is invalid.

Comment: @Bart van Ingen Schenau, this is not covered in specs. However, users _can_ run app in bad network conditions, and I believe application must not crash under any conditions.

Comment: *any circumstances* also includes the PCI bus that stops working or memory chips that break down. But it also does not have to be spelled out in the spec, as long as you can apply some common sense. If it is unspecified what other devices/services are on the same network as your application, then bad network conditions are logically to be expected once in a while.

Comment: @Bart van Ingen Schenau, application is supposed to be used by numerous users all over the world.

Comment: So, the application is supposed to work under bad network conditions (that's what I as user would expect; you can't control that I am also streaming several videos at the same time). Should be sufficient grounds to claim that you uncovered a bug.

Comment: For the record, I hate questions like this.  You know the answer you want.  You've told us the answer you want us to give.  How we get there is the only detail left unanswered.  But what if I think you're wrong?  Or, as in this case, "it depends".  In many languages you're right.  But in both Erlang and Go, it would be fine to have huge numbers of threads, while async would be a bad design.

Comment: @btilly, actually it's .net

Comment: Gut feelings don't cut it, and I've seen plenty of single-threaded applications that crash with time.  What have you done to prove that the crash is actually caused by the presence of so many threads?

Comment: @Blrfl, "crash is actually caused by the presence of so many threads" is off the question, this has already proven.

Comment: So the application crashes "by design" and that is "not a bug"? There is nothing much left to discuss, I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spawning a new thread for each task is not necessarily a bad design, but there are some factors that need to be taken into consideration:

- Context switching between threads takes time. If the number of runnable threads becomes very large (an order of magnitude larger than the number of cores/processors you have), then this can negatively affect the perceived performance of the application
- There are only so many threads you can create. If there is no upper limit to the number of threads that an application creates, then the application will run out of resources sooner or later.
- Creating a new thread is a heavy-weight operation. If you create a new thread for every short-running task, you might find that the thread creation takes a significant portion of the time that those threads 'exist'. Using a work queue and a thread pool might actually increase the performance of the application.

Answer (score 10):

I'm sure you need to explain to them what [Thread Pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) is. And that each solid framework does have one implemented and people who implemented it are most probably many times better than themselves at solving this kind of problems.

Comment: Change `better` to `have more experience`. You do not want to antagonize your public :-)

Comment: @SJuan76, "have more experience" is enough to antagonize as well ;)

Answer (score 2):

Don't manually manage threads if you don't have to and instead try to use a thread pool. Pretty much all languages and runtimes that support threads also have a thread pool implementation built into the standard library. So using threads in and of itself is not a bad idea but manually managing threads can get out of hand pretty quickly so in the beginning try to stick with whatever high level thread management comes built-in.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to propose a solution to people who don't think they have a problem. Your app crashing under certain circumstances is considered acceptable. Like everything there is a level of risk and reward. You can try to approach in one or both directions.

1. Will "it was designed that way" be acceptable to users/customers? Personally, I'd suggest the design is flawed (and the designer is an idiot for intentionally doing this) and needs to change because I'll go find an app that doesn't crash. Do your collegues want to face these complaints? Maybe it is easier to just fix it?
2. Is the fix that difficult? Lots of suggestions give about frameworks that take care of threads for the most part. How difficult would they be to use?

"That's the way it was designed." "This is the way we always did it." If they want to argue that customers don't care and/or the fix is too difficult to make because of more important features or risk of further hindering the application would sound a lot more like they've given this some thought.